# Interpolation using trigonometric polynomials of bounded modulus

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, trigonometry, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Consider a grid of points $T=\{t_1,\ldots,t_m\}$ with $0\le t_i\le 1$. I would like to derive conditions on $t_1,\ldots,t_m$ (interpolation points) under which for any sequence of complex numbers $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_m\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|c_k|=1$, there exists a function $f(t):[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ of the form
\begin{equation*}
f(t)=\sum_{k=-n}^n a_k e^{2\pi i k t}
\end{equation*}

(with n as small as possible) such that

1) $f(t)$ interpolates $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_m\in\mathbb{C}$ on $T$. That is
\begin{equation*}
f(t_k)=c_k
\end{equation*}

2) $|f(t)|< 1$ for $t\notin T$.

I know that the condition on the interpolation nodes $t_1,\ldots,t_m$ should look something like the ones appearing below

1) $min_{k,\ell}|t_k-t_\ell|\ge 1/n$

(with the distance meant to be circular that is |0.9-0.1|=0.2).

or

2) more sophisticated conditions like:

$D_{m}(t_1,\ldots,t_m)$ needs to be small. The discrepancy of a a finite sequence of real numbers $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N\in[0,1]$ is defined as 
\begin{equation*}
D_N(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N)=\underset{0\le\alpha<\beta\le 1}{sup}\bigg|\frac{A([\alpha,\beta);N)}{N}-(\beta-\alpha)\bigg|,
\end{equation*}
with $A([\alpha,\beta);N)$ denoting the number of $x_i$ such that $x_i\in[\alpha,\beta)$ (Based on section 2 of Uniform Distribution of Sequences by Kuipers and Niederreiter).

Comment: This looks vaguely like the [boundary Nevanlinna-Pick interpolation  problem](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=boundary+Nevanlinna-pick+interpolation) where one is looking for a holomorphic function of unit disk to itself with interpolation nodes on the boundary. You also want a function that maps unit disk to itself, and your interpolation nodes are also on the boundary. The difference is that you want a harmonic polynomial $\sum_{k=-n}^n a_k z^k$ rather than a holomorphic functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be Proposition 2.1 from [this paper](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/super-res.pdf). The bound they give (in  Theorem 1.2 there) is $$\min_{k,l}|t_k-t_l| \geq 2/n, $$
the distance $|t_k-t_l|$ here is the distance between $t_k$ and $t_l$ on a torus, like a wrap-around distance, and they also assume $n\geq128$.

Comment: For completeness, I add that they also assume $n\ge 128$. Thanks for the answer (which will get the bounty in due course), but I can't help thinking that there should be a more conceptual proof than 10 pages  of numerical computations...

Comment: I added the assumption on $n$ to the answer.

Comment: thanks, I am actually familiar with that paper. I'm looking for the more conceptual proof and generalizable to the discrepancy notion above. Did not want to cloud people's thought with the paper.

Comment: And yes I'm looking exactly for a trigonometric analogue to the boundary Nevanlinna-Pick interpolation problem.

Answer (score 0):

I now think that using the following should work 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_k c_k{\bigg(\prod_{k\neq \ell}\frac{\sin \pi (t-t_\ell)}{\sin \pi (t_k-t_\ell)}\bigg)}^2
\end{equation*}
I'm trying to see what's the best way to control each term in absolute value using the notion of discrepancy.

The reason I expect this to work is that the mentioned product decays fast enough like (1/t^2) so that when we sum them up it still remains less than one. Also when the $t_\ell$ are grid points $i/N$ the product becomes the Fejer kernel or the square of the Dirichlet kernel ${({\frac{\sin(\pi/N*t)}{N\sin(\pi*t)}})}^2$, which is always less than one. So we would be done if we can bound the difference between the Fejer kernel and the above kernels. Noting that if we where dealing with the grid points the answer would be the Fejer kernel.